# No debuggable processes in logcat when phone detected by Android studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, samsung-mobile

Everyone!

I got so confused by android studio.
when I plug in my phone to debug apps, logcat can detect my phone, but I can not choose process. It said "no debuggable processes",not common "no debuggable applications".

My phone is samsung s5 (android 6.0),rooted.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Enable ADB integration using Tools->Android

Comment: for me I had to run an emulator with Oreo... not what I want but the only thing that worked

Comment: first of all, make sure that this is not a release version )

Answer (score 78):

I had a similar issue, when I was building an app, I could select the device in Logcat, but not the process. (same message, "No Debuggable Processes")

The reason: I was building my app in **release**, then, when I changed the build variants to **debug**, I was able to select the process.

Comment: This was exactly my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Note that debuggable may be set to true in release as well. Optional but maybe not recommended depending on you application.

Comment: that's the right answer! Thanks, i did not know that!

Answer (score 54):

You need to enable `adb integration`, just go to `Tools`-->`Android`-->Check `Enable ADB Integration`

It was a default feature a few versions ago but now it's disabled by default

Comment: this should be the answer. +1

Comment: Yes, they removed it in last Android Studio version. Go to `File`-->`Settings`-->`Build, Execution, Deployment`-->`Debugger` and ensure that the `Logcat output` options are checked

Answer (score 42):

This happens time to time, try these three options in any order:

1. Restart Android Studio ( preferably with invalidated caches as well )
2. Restart your phone
3. Deactivate and reactivate usb debugging

Comment: What about the cable ? There are cables out there, that have only power transfer capability..

Comment: I can use adb in cmd console with the same cable,it works well.so.... I don't know the root cause about this phenomenon.

Comment: "Restart Android Studio" worked like a charm for me.

Comment: after tried all these solutions its not working for me.

Answer (score 41):

In my case, using Android Studio 3.1.3, I had to enable "Use libusb backend" checkbox at File-->Settings-->Build, Execution, Deployment-->Debugger

Comment: Worked for me using a Google Pixel 2. Thanks!

Comment: This setting is not where it is specified above.  I have 3.1.3 installed and the setting does not exist in that window.

Comment: You saved my life! 
A little update to this answer, on newer versions of Android Studio, you should go to:  Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger

Comment: Doesn't work on mac though. Will give you an error when you try to debug the app.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770464/installation-did-not-succeed-the-application-could-not-be-installed-installati

Comment: Sweet! Thank you

Answer (score 20):

one of the reasons is that your application is marked as not debuggable in the `build.gradle` file

```
buildTypes{
    release{
        debuggable false
    }
}
```

another reason maybe you did not allow ADB integration.
You should have Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration active

Comment: After reading this answer I set "debuggable true" in a custom signed debug variant and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

1. Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Exception, Deployment -> Debugger -> **check** "Use libusb backend" -> Apply -> OK
2. Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Exception, Deployment -> Debugger -> **uncheck** "Use libusb backend" -> Apply -> OK
3. oh, it's just work now ... (my android studio version is 4.1)

Answer (score 7):

Open terminal window at botton ba..
type
adb kill-server
adb start_server

Comment: Best answer. It works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

if you set `minifyenabled` to `true` you can be face with this error. So if you run your app release or debug then be sure that `minifyenabled` is `false`.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found that I was running a release version of the App. So foolish...

Comment: Great! I didn't know I have to set `debuggable true` explicitly in the `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have recently launched Android Device Monitor which might have prompted you to disable ADB integration. Usually, when you exit the Android Device Monitor, ABD integration is automatically re-enabled. But sometimes it isn't, so please check `Tools/Android/Enable ADB Integration`

Comment: Indeed this was not re-enabled by default for me as well

Comment: Great tip. I found that I had to use Task Manager to kill process monitor.exe running in the background to restore the normality.

Answer (score 4):

**1. Open Edit Configurations:**

[image]

**2. Check the boxes:**

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to use the App Inspection Tab to check my app's database and I am seeing this "No debuggable process" when selecting my device. How do I go about this? Because this did not work

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't believe but this is really simple, took me long to find it out, but u don't need any solution here, actually there is nothing wrong, just:

1. Right click your MainActivity class, (or whatever you name it)
2. Click on Run "MainActivity"
3. Solved!

I think this happens when updating the gradle, at least for me.
Hope works for anyone looking around.
(Sorry for my english)

Comment: wooooow this worked for me, after  One week search :x

Answer (score 1):

Click the "Bug" icon and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same of my problem and I solve it by install android studio 4.1.3 from this link :
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

or this directly

https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/4.1.3.0/android-studio-ide-201.7199119-windows.exe   for windows

for MAC
https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/4.1.3.0/android-studio-ide-201.7199119-mac.dmg

Answer (score 0):

If all does not work then try checking your manifest file, set:

```
android:debuggable="true".
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe U can reboot your PC/Mac. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the case, when you change cable with new one, then Restart is required for Android Studio. It will prompt USB debugging again.

Answer (score 0):

Unplugged the test device from USB and plugged it back in, that did it for me. Restarting Android Studio had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
adb kill-server
adb devices // restart in case it doesn't do it by itself
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a debuggable app that has stopped logging accidentally restarting android studio is the only helpful solution ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this issue.

1. Restart you Android Studio.
2. Your Application should be in debug mode.
3. Device should be connected.

Answer (score 0):

My case is not like other's answers.

I just click `Remove from sidebar` on  tab  by right click.

Then enable it  in  `View -> Tool window  -> Profiler`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to download usb drivers for your phone (in this case as I see, it is a samsung s5). The link to its drivers is this one:

http://samsungusbdriver.com/download/samsung-driver-v1-5-61-0

When you are there, follow the steps when downloaded and your phone will be recognised. Hope I could help ;).

Comment: I don't know then. Maybe you didn't do 1 important thing - when you plug your phone in, when you pull down that little menu in it you should see usb file transfer. If not yet done, select "transferring media files" so it works.

Comment: I can transfer file correctly.because of my reputation on  this web,i can not upload picture. or you can see the phenomenon.

Comment: That is pretty sad. If you could explain what you did overall I could try helping you a bit more.

Comment: I got the answer,maybe it can only debug the app that in your project.i want to debug others' app via attache process. Thanks a lot! you are so kind!