# I cannot check debug method in android studio using my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I cannot check debug method in android studio using my phone.using other phones or emulators it work perfectly.when i connect my phone into studio the log-cat values are again & again loading.so i can't find any issue or debug.

my log-cat :

[image]

what can i do?what is the problem to connect my phone?

Comment: if this happens occasionally then try restarting adb

Comment: also try this.not happen.again logcat work like same issue

Comment: if the dropdown with "No Debuggable Processes" never changes then try to "invalidate cache and restart" android studio and if possible also update studio to latest version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No debuggable processes in android studio when connected with phone which runs android 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033849/no-debuggable-processes-in-android-studio-when-connected-with-phone-which-runs-a)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to choose your application in "No Debuggable Processes" toggle ?