# Android Studio Error "Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. Installation failed due to: 'null'"

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, failed-installation, xiaomi

I am trying to run my app on a real Android device using Android Studio v3.5. It throws the following error while installing the app.

```
> Installation did not succeed.  
> The application could not be installed.  
> Installation failed due to: 'null'
```

Comment: Check this please : 
stackoverflow.com/questions/57589248/installation-failed-due-to-null-android-studio-3-5

Comment: Its a different case. I have tried this. It does not work

Comment: What's the Android version? Have you tried applying other answers?

Comment: In my case, problem was emulator ends storage free

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had the Same issue on a MAC, this is how I solve it,
note: I was tried the method that mention @Manoj Kumar,

Un check this field in Preferences/Build,Execution,Deployment/Debugger
[image]

Comment: there is no such a thing in my settings! though when i am searching libusb it tracks exactly to this location! what should i do?

Comment: How about an emulator? I'm using Memuplay

Comment: In my case, the option was unchecked, and succeed after checking it.

Comment: This option no more available in latest android studio

Comment: It works in my Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Canary 3

Comment: In my case, problem was emulator ends storage free –

Comment: I had the same problem with running the app on my physical phone, turning this feature on solved my issue.

Answer (score 28):

Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: This works for me, and I can rate it as the best answer here. Thanks @basavaraj

Answer (score 20):

1.Open run/debug configuration dialog:-
   Run> edit configurations.

2. Navigate to You app > General > Installation Options > Install Flags.
3. add install flags `-r -t`.

Note: This flags means adb install `-r -t` apk path

[image]

I hope this will help.

Comment: Its a different case. I have tried this. It does not work

Comment: so are you running this application in an emulator or in a real device?

Comment: Real Device: Xiaomi Redmi S2.

Comment: Any idea with this error? `Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill -r -t --skip-verification -S 11805591' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package''`

Answer (score 12):

For me, restarting the Android Studio solved the issue.

File> Invalidate Cache / Restart

Comment: This worked for me when apps wouldn't install using wireless debugging.

Answer (score 6):

When you connect the mobile, it starts in the ***charging mode***.
Simply change the mode to **Transfer Mode** (Transfer Media or photos mode).

Now install the app again and it will work.

Comment: OH MY GOD!!! I spend multiple hours trying to fix this, toggling usb debugging, developer options, resetting authorizations, data and even factory resetting the device... Why isn't this switched automatically when you enable USB debugging???

Comment: The libusb backend check option didn't help on Linux as suggested by another user. So unchecked, restarted PC. Then on the phone Selected `USB Tethering` on `'Developer Options' > 'Default USB configuration'`. This is with Android Studio Giraffe.

Answer (score 6):

**Restarting** the device after enabling developer mode and allowing usb debugging did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

It may be because of your phone's memory is full. you can delete some data from your phone and then try. for me it worked.

Comment: yepp, my case. Have uninstalled some apps and now it plays ok again

Answer (score 4):

1. You has installed  the app which has same package name  with different debug signature file.
2. The different signature file  lead to the fault
3. At first please uninstall the apk that you has installed with different signature  file。
4. Then you install the apk again ,You'll sucess!

Answer (score 4):

Tip: run from terminal `adb install path/to/app.apk`

Why? Cause it will give more information about the error - actually pointing to the place in manifest with the error. For example - in my case it was: 'Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]'

Comment: Thanks a lot, this indeed led to an easy fix of the problem. The whole command with the default path where the auto-generated apks are stored is then as follows:
`adb install app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk`

Answer (score 1):

A simple (unintended) restart to the computer did it for me (I tried to run on emulator)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using third party library, I have removed that library from gradle and reinstall the app.  Successful

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your '/gradle.properties':

```
# gradle.properties
android.injected.testOnly=false
```

Check https://gist.github.com/xujiaao/5fd127a72979cdc3c70dcc1324786f87 ,it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just use in this link. Disable Preference -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Debugger -> Use libusb backend

Uncheck **Use libusb backend**

that's all. Enjoy your coding...

Answer (score 1):

Its because the devie on which you want to install the app does not have enough space, just clear some items to get space. Then try agian

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69424366/2227743

Comment: Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced this same error while running application. I am just rebuild the program and run again the application..

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33463135)

Answer (score 0):

Chech to manifest file and search for a required library tag. And delete it. I solve it by this way.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying everything but nothing seemed to work. But then I suddenly noticed that my phone blocked installation, so I unchecked "reject this to install" and at the another try the security checkbox popup, asking for letting the installation. After allowing everything worked.
Conclusion: I just were probably too angry that i didn't noticed this popup earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Just check in the AndroidManifest.xml file to make sure you are using permission and libraries that you need for your app. In some cases you may have wearable libraries and permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file and yet you do not need them. This happened to me when I was adding more activities and Android Studio was creating them as Wearable Activities

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying every thing from the answers but only one solution is just free some space on your phone for proper install the debagged app.

Comment: This recommendation was already provided. Instead of creating a duplicate answer, it's better to add a comment on the original answer, or simply up-vote it.

Comment: Or you can upvote an existing answer if it is the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

For me ı had this problem  i fixed it
because i did not use Android studio Emulator i was using another one
i fixed the problem when I enabled Developer Mode from Emulator
and that is all for
I hope that can help some one like me
Regards

Comment: The question mentions that it's related to a real device not an emulator. Please read through the question thoroughly before answering.

Comment: Ok no problem dear my answer also can help someone.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem at one point in time. the only solution that worked for me was to delete the SDK and download a new vision. It turned out that ADB had a problem and it was not able to detect my device. uninstalling the SDK and installing another resolved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

As I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA 2021,
In order to work for me, I had to disconnect android device(Emulator)
to Computer by USB and Free up some space on phone storage
Lastly It was to **refresh my device** by restarting it(phone)

Again, I had to go to:

**Settings, Debugger,**
And Check **Hide debug Window on process termination**

I hope this helps, if U are using IntelliJ IDEA, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a signed apk and drag that apk to the emulated device, that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You might wana check your phone storage too. Your apk wouldn't install if there is no space

Comment: This has already been mentioned in several other answers. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by switching off the emulator, clean the project and rebuild it again.

Answer (score 0):

go to the path of your debug apk, and rename of your apk like :

**myApp.apk** to **myApp1.apk**(just rename it)
and try to run it again.

its works for me every time :)

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS!

- Delete the build folder in your App and re-build the project, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Accept agreement of terms and conditions by opening Google Maps and Google Chrome on a newly created emulator, your application might be using Google play or location services.

Answer (score 0):

Wiping the data of the emulator solved the case for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkWJJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth checking if your `build.gradle` has the line `archivesBaseName="text"` where `"text"` contains spaces or characters from different languages. In my case this was the problem