# Installation failed due to: 'closed' Errors | Anroid Studio 4.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

When I click the run button in Android studio(4.0.2 for Windows 64-bit), I get the following error.

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\XXX\AndroidStudioProjects\IlkProje\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'closed'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvRN1.png)

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58492367/8377985

Comment: @NihthiyaAlthaf In Android Studio 4.0.2;
The feature specified in the Debugger tab does not appear.

Comment: @Brahin Okay.. which device u are using? Emulator or real device?

Comment: I use emulator.

Comment: Cool.. Check another answer below

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

1.Open run/debug configuration dialog:- Run> edit configurations.

Navigate to You app > General > Installation Options > Install Flags.
add install flags -r -t.

Note: This flags means adb install -r -t apk path

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem has not been solved. : /

Comment: Try clean & rebuild.. If the same error occurs try to disabling instant run option from Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run