# INSTALL_FAILED_ABORTED error on Huawei P40 Pro (ELS-NX9)

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm trying to migrate our existing app the Huawei App Gallery. In order to test the Huawei AGC, I tried installing a sample Android app to this  Huawei P40 Pro (ELS-NX9) device, but I keep getting this error. This app is nothing but a basic app in Android studio. I have configured the project according to Huawei AGC instructions as well.

This is what I get

> Launching 'app' on Physical Device.
>
> Installation did not succeed.
>
> The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_ABORTED
>
> Installation failed due to: 'null'
>
> Retry

**However, I can install the same app in other physical devices.**

My Android studio version is 4.1.1

I tried the given tips on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770464/installation-did-not-succeed-the-application-could-not-be-installed-installati), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589248/installation-failed-due-to-null-android-studio-3-5) and several other questions relevant to similar issues but still no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try the following steps below:

1. Enable **Developer options**.
2. Disable **Monitor apps installed by ADB**.

[image: Monitor apps installed by ADB]

Result:
[image: Result-Monitor apps installed by ADB]