# Android Studio - INSTALLATION DID NOT SUCCEED

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-developer-api

How to Fix This Error while using physical device as emulator.....???????

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'null'

I use Android Studio Version 4.1.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Error "Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. Installation failed due to: 'null'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770464/android-studio-error-installation-did-not-succeed-the-application-could-not-be)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the device emulator and click on troubleshoot device connections.

- If it doesn't automatically scans your device rescan it again,
- Then on the next part just click on restart ADB server finally click on finish.

I think it will fix the issue with install parse.