# Android Studio | 4.2 | Arctic Fox | not showing debuggable processes

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating AndroidStudio to `4.2` I can't see my apps in debuggable  process. every things was ok just before update. what I tried but nothing changed is:

- restart my phone

- restart android studio

- restart pc

- invalidate caches

- rebuild & clean

- remove build folder

- disable developer option in my phone

- try on emulator

Comment: Seems that google messed there something up. Related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195956684
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195754565
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195629683
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195108338
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195092348
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194915681
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194911972

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately after 2 days wasting my time and doing all suggested things In [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033849/no-debuggable-processes-in-android-studio-when-connected-with-phone-which-runs-a) , I downgraded android studio to 4.1.3 and now it is working like before update. It also maybe useful for others that I also checked `android studio arctic fox canary 15` and nothing differs with `4.2`

**Update** 
For developers who are living in Iran maybe it's related to sanctions. I was using vpn to change my ip when updating sdk . after version 4.2 is released google use more ways to identify where we are come from and two possible of them is `Region` and `Regional Format`. therefore You should change them to another country and then update sdk to solve the problem.

Comment: I downgraded from v4.2.2 to v4.1.3 and now its working well as before

Answer (score 3):

Just change windows `Regional Format` to `English`. Windows Settings -> Time & Language -> Region -> Regional Format . Then restart android studio

Comment: This answer helped me thank you

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED:
change your time-zone and format to USA, it worked for me

Comment: Change format is required too.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: Resetting Android Studio

File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings…

Comment: Thank you for your solution. In my case problem was google sanctions against Iran

Comment: Since I found at least 8 similar bug reports on the official bug tracker: I guess that you found a different workaround.

Comment: This not working for me and bad solution

Comment: Not working: fine, but why bad solution?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging works fine after updating Android Studio to 4.2.. My app is also showing in Debuggable processes under Logcat..