# I can't see App error in "Run" Logcat in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

After updating Android Studio to version 4.2.1, I can not see my application errors in the "run" section on Logcat. Logcat is in *No Debuggable Processes* mode. please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033849/no-debuggable-processes-in-android-studio-when-connected-with-phone-which-runs-a hope this solve your problem.

Comment: @vikram Thank you for your answer. I have seen this question before and tried all the solutions. But unfortunately none of them were my answer.