# No debuggable processes is visible since Android Studio 4.2

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

After updating my android studio to version 4.2 I have no debuggable processes in Logcat to select. The build variant is debug for sure, and I already checked the other StackOverflow posts that address my issue but didn't find anything. Also, I tried older versions and it turned out that 4.1.3 doesn't have this issue and processes are visible, but I have this problem with the 4.2 and 4.2.1 and BumbleBee, It seems there is something wrong with new versions. I'm wondering if someone else had the same problem, Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** Even debugger can't attach to the process

[image]

Comment: just go to Tools-->Android-->Check Enable ADB Integration

Comment: run app again and leave the logcat do not minimize it

Comment: There is no such option in version 4.+, I think it is removed @UsamaAltaf

Comment: view --> tool windows --> build variant .. then select debug

Comment: My build variant is already debug @MajidAli

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033849/no-debuggable-processes-in-logcat-when-phone-detected-by-android-studio

Comment: Believe me, I already tried all of this before posting my question :)

Comment: I faced this problem few days ago and I realized that the `Android Device Monitor (DDMS)` works well with no problem. So I think the problem is with new update of Android Studio. You can temporarily use DDMS from `%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/monitor.bat` but I dont know how to fix the bug :(

Comment: I guess downgrade to previous versions of Android Studio may fix the problem. I will inform you if I found the solution. Please tell me if you findout how to solve this. thanks in advance

Comment: @FarshadTahmasbi I don't know If you still have this issue, I just updated my android studio to BumbleBee and I had this problem. This answer helped me resolve it. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71052598/2844833)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, As I mentioned in the comments I tried almost everything but It didn't work, Eventually, I had to install Windows again (Windows 10), I don't know why but I guess there was something wrong with the OS.

**Note**: I had this issue with Android Studio 4.2 and 4.2.1 but 4.1.3 was OK.

Answer (score 8):

This is a **bug** with some **Windows OS datetime formats** (such as Persian or Arabic formats) in Android Studio version 4.2 and higher.

We just need to use `English (United States)` format to avoid this problem. (Tested on version 4.2 and Arctic Fox both)

**How to do**: In windows 10 Go to `Control Panel > Region > Formats` and choose `English (United States)` from dropdown menu.

**Edit**: I have reported this bug in issue tracker. So you can give it a star to make sure Google will fix it in next release of Android Studio:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210299312

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I have been in this issue since long time , your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue by starting version 4.2 and I tried all stable and beta versions that came out after that and sadly problem still is there now. One thing that takes my attention is that everywhere I look up for a way to solve this I saw Iranian developers. because of that I guessed this problem (specially mean after version 4.2) is a sort of google sanctions

**Update**
as I guessed it's related to sanctions and you should change `Region` and `Regional Format` to another country to solve problem

Comment: Thanks for the response, Eventually I had to install windows again and now it's working! I have no idea what the problem was.

Comment: glad to hear that. I should do the same!

Comment: @vahid How did you solved the problem? I faced this problem a few days ago after updating and I'm getting crazy of that! please help me!

Comment: @Homayoon Ahmadi In fact, I have not been able to solve this problem yet. after Farshad Tahmasbi mentioned I tried it on a fresh windows and works, but I do that on vmware just for testing. I'm looking for a way to solve it on my current windows without installing a fresh one

Comment: @vahid Have you tried to use a previous version of Android Studio?

Comment: @Homayoon Ahmadi yes, versions before 4.2 working well but every version after that no

Comment: This also solves another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68973640/android-studio-layout-designer-creates-numbers-in-persian/69222505#69222505

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on specific version but can not remember right now. My solution was kill and restart adb.

In command go to folder: **sdk/platform-tools/**  Then run:

```
adb kill-server
```

And then run:

```
adb start-server
```

This should reconnect adb and you will find proper process to connect to in Android studio.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Already tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue few days ago. Didn't see this method tried here so I'll try to describe it. Nothing helped me, I tried to invalidate cache, reinstall command line tools, Android Studio, update it to latest version.

What resolved the issue for me was going to `File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings` and going through IDE setup again.

Comment: The only one solution that really helped to restore Logcat. Thank you!